# How to using cfg80211->start_ap?

Tags: wifi

I want to start an AP in the kernel by using `API(start_ap)` in struct `cfg80211_ops`, but I can only create an AP without a password.

What should I do to create an AP with WPA-PSK mode?

Answer (score 0):

You should set **struct cfg80211_crypto_settings** in **struct cfg80211_ap_settings**.
You can see example of it into **nl80211.c**: function **nl80211_start_ap**.
It invoke **nl80211_crypto_settings** for setting this crypto struct.